# prove $\sum |{x_n}|$ converges, then $\sum {x_n}$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I need to prove that $\sum |{x_n}|$ converges, then $\sum {x_n}$ converges too. However, isn't this false and the converse is true instead?

Comment: Series $|(\frac{(-1)^n}{n})|$ do not converge, however series $\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ do

Comment: @DominikKutek OP seems to need to go the other way

Comment: Uh, U're right, I've misunderstood it

Comment: Have you heard of the Cauchy criterion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

Note that $x_n \le |x_n|$, and then $x_n \ge -|x_n|$,

hence $-\sum |x_n|\le\sum x_n \le \sum |x_n|$.

Comment: Shouldn't "$<$" be "$\leq$"?

Comment: @MartinRosenau True, but that is really not that important in this case.

Comment: so, by squeeze therorem, $\sum x_n$ converges too? But how do you know the negative sum of $|x_n|$ will converges too? and one more question, there's no limit involves ?!

Comment: In what way does this show convergence ? It only shows boundedness.

Comment: @MathAvengers, it does not follow by the squeeze theorem, i.e., that is not the idea here

Comment: @YvesDaoust, this is only a hint

Comment: @MathAvengers If $\sum |x_n| = L$ then $-\sum |x_n| = -L$...

Comment: @YvesDaoust indeed only a hint, thank you AnotherJohnDoe

Comment: In what way is it helpful ?

Comment: @AnotherJohnDoe So... should a imply limit to it and that since limit of $-\sum {x_n}$ converges to ${x_n}$ and limit $+\sum {x_n}$ also converges to ${x_n}$; by squeeze theorem , limit $\sum {x_n}$ will also converges to ${x_n}$, hence it is converges ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust, we can satisfy the Cauchy criterion for $\sum x_n$

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |x_n| < \infty$, and consider the sequence $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^\infty x_i$ of partial sums.  Then we will show $(S_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is a Cauchy sequence and therefore has a limit.  Note that for $m < n$, we have
$$ |S_n - S_m| = \left| \sum_{i=m+1}^n x_n \right| \le \sum_{i=m+1}^n |x_i| \le \sum_{i=m+1}^\infty |x_i|. $$
However, as $m \to \infty$, the right hand side approaches a limit of zero.  From this, the Cauchy property of $(S_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ will follow with a little work.

Comment: why is the right hand side approaches 0, shouldn't it be x ? (i.e ${x_n} --> {x}$)

Comment: If $S_n'$ is the sequence of partial sums of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |x_n|$ with limit $S'$, then $\sum_{i=m+1}^\infty |x_i| = S' - S_m' \to S' - S' = 0$.

Comment: so, since the right side converges to 0, which means there exists an $\epsilon>0$ that is larger than the right side, which is also larger than the left side accordingly. Hence, the left side converges ? Am I on the right track ? Thank s!!

Answer (score 0):

The other answer I presented is a very general solution, and is one that you'll probably see again if you go on to study functional analysis, and Banach spaces in particular.

On the other hand, for the case of real sequences (and a similar argument will also work for complex sequences), there is another solution which you might find more intuitive.  The basic idea is that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n|$ converging implies that the positive terms and the negative terms both have converging sums by the comparison theorem for series of nonnegative sequences.

To make the argument precise, given $x \in \mathbb{R}$, we will define
$$ x^+ := \begin{cases} x, & x \ge 0;\\ 0, & x < 0, \end{cases} \mathrm{~and~} x^- := \begin{cases} 0, & x \ge 0;\\ -x, & x < 0. \end{cases}$$
Then I will leave it as an exercise to show that for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$, we have $0 \le x^+, x^- \le |x|$; $x = x^+ - x^-$; and $|x| = x^+ + x^-$.

Now, by the comparison theorem (comparing to $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |x_n|$), we get that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n^+$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n^-$ are both convergent series.  Therefore, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (x_n^+ - x_n^-)$ is also a convergent series.

Answer (score 0):

$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_k.$

$T_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n}|x_k|.$

$T_n$ converges, implies $T_n$ is a Cauchy sequence.

$\epsilon >0$ given, there is a $n_0$, s.t.

for $m \ge n \ge n_0$:

$|T_m-T_n|= |\sum_{k=n+1}^{m}|x_k|| <\epsilon$;

We have:

$|S_m-S_n| = |\sum_{k=n+1}^{m}x_k| \le $

$|\sum_{k=n+1}^{m}|x_k||= |T_m-T_n| \lt \epsilon$ .

$S_n$ is Cauchy, hence convergent.